# Unable to install ocurl by opam

Tags: opam

I got an error on installing ocurl 0.9.2 while installing google-drive-ocamlfuse by opam.

ERROR] The compilation of ocurl failed at "/home/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build make".

pragma message: libcurl does not provide CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET
pragma message: libcurl does not provide CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION
pragma message("libcurl does not provide CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION")

curl-helper.c:2511:13: ??: 双caml_HTTP_VERSION・???????????????? [-Wunused-function] static long ocaml_HTTP_VERSION(long curl_version)

Does anybody have the same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of curl, specifically the libcurl libraries, is too old.  The ocurl package needs a couple of features that aren't in the version you have.

I upgraded mine from 7.31 to 7.79, and it worked.